# gradle project refresh failed: protocol family unavailable

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When I started android studio my project is loaded and displays gradle sync in progress after some time it says:

```
     Gradle 'SMSTest' project refresh failed:
     Protocol family unavailable
     Gradle settings
```

Comment: what happened no answer

Comment: Please add the contents of your build.gradle files to your question.

Comment: I had the same error message "Protocol family unavailable" when I open gradle project in eclipse and then in IntelliJ IDEA - of course I didn't close eclipse. After eclipse was closed, I restart IDEA and problem went away. I know it's not solution for Your problem, but it may be a good trace...